# C++ Builder XE, dbExpress with MySQL 5.x

Tags: mysql, c++builder, dbexpress, c++builder-xe

I'm trying to get the dbExpress `TSQLConnection` to work with a MySQL 5.x server.
I have searched the net but not found any helpfull instruction for C++ Builder XE.

I downloaded the `dbxopenmysql50.dll` driver from [just software solutions](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/delphi/dbexpress_and_mysql_5.html) and followed the instructions on their site.

I downloaded the `libmysql.dll` from [mysql](http://mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) and put the dll's in the bin folder of C++ Builder XE and edited the dbxdrivers.ini to use the new DLLs.

In the IDE when I tset the `TSQLConnection` property connected to true, the dbxopenmysql50.dll crash with `Access Violation in address` bla bla bla...

I don't care about my current setup, but is there ANYONE that have this working?
How did you make it work? Please direct me where to download free working DLLs for dbExpress with MySQL 5.x

Here is some more error information:

`"Access violation in address 10395D99 in module 'dbxopenmysql50.dll'. Read of 
address 0275C8D".`

Detailed dump from C++ Builder XE Error dialog.

```
(00004D99){dbxopenmysql50.dll} [10395D99]
[50037560]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@FreeMem (Line 3768, "System.pas" + 20) + $0
[500415CF]{rtl150.bpl  } System.LocaleCharsFromUnicode (Line 29632, "System.pas" + 1) + $17
[50052A6C]{rtl150.bpl  } SysUtils.StrPosLen (Line 9617, "SysUtils.pas" + 8) + $13
[5003D9B4]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@UStrDelete (Line 22863, "System.pas" + 10) + $5
[50037560]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@FreeMem (Line 3768, "System.pas" + 20) + $0
[5003C0B0]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@UStrClr (Line 16968, "System.pas" + 14) + $0
[500A0F89]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.TStrings.GetValueFromIndex (Line 5756, "Classes.pas" + 12) + $10
[51D1B35B]{DbxCommonDriver150.bpl} Dbxdynalink.TDBXDynalinkDriverCommonLoader.LoadDriverLibraryAndMethodTable + $E3
[51D1AFE9]{DbxCommonDriver150.bpl} Dbxdynalink.TDBXDynalinkDriver.LoadDriver + $35
[51D1DCD8]{DbxCommonDriver150.bpl} Dbxdynalinknative.TDBXDynalinkDriverNative.CreateConnection + $C
[51CF0C19]{DbxCommonDriver150.bpl} Dbxcommon.TDBXDelegateDriver.CreateConnection + $5
[51CF6666]{DbxCommonDriver150.bpl} Dbxcommon.TDBXConnectionBuilder.CreateConnection + $B6
[51CE7B5C]{DbxCommonDriver150.bpl} Dbxcommon.TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection + $E8
[51CE7A6D]{DbxCommonDriver150.bpl} Dbxcommon.TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection + $5
[50FFC77F]{dbexpress150.bpl} SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.DoConnect (Line 2537, "SqlExpr.pas" + 52) + $5
[5070E10D]{dbrtl150.bpl} DB.TCustomConnection.SetConnected (Line 3167, "DB.pas" + 8) + $4
[50089A3E]{rtl150.bpl  } TypInfo.SetOrdProp (Line 1791, "TypInfo.pas" + 28) + $0
[2105A0A6]{designide150.bpl} DesignEditors.TPropertyEditor.SetOrdValue (Line 841, "DesignEditors.pas" + 2) + $E
[2109E55B]{designide150.bpl} VCLEditors.TBooleanProperty.MouseUp (Line 1840, "VCLEditors.pas" + 5) + $10
[21194BD9]{vclide150.bpl} PropBox.TCustomPropListBox.ItemMouseUp (Line 1625, "PropBox.pas" + 16) + $1B
[21194DCF]{vclide150.bpl} PropBox.TCustomPropListBox.MouseUp (Line 1690, "PropBox.pas" + 1) + $D
[5027E90C]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.DoMouseUp (Line 7318, "Controls.pas" + 2) + $28
[5027E988]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WMLButtonUp (Line 7331, "Controls.pas" + 9) + $6
[2119A4C0]{vclide150.bpl} IDEInspListBox.TInspListBox.WMLButtonUp (Line 1631, "IDEInspListBox.pas" + 3) + $4
[5027DF6C]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7074, "Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[06D19928]{AQtime7BDS8.bpl} Aqsyncedit.TaqEditPainter.HasHintInfo + $9B8
[502820C3]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg (Line 9608, "Controls.pas" + 1) + $9
[50282830]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9831, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[502B8409]{vcl150.bpl  } StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.WndProc (Line 6217, "StdCtrls.pas" + 54) + $6
[50281ED0]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9552, "Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[500AFA64]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13491, "Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[50358AF7]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 9760, "Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50358B3A]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 9790, "Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50358E65]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 9927, "Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Access violation in address bla bla bla" isn't helpful. If you can't put forth the effort to provide the actual error message, it's pretty hard to want to put forth the effort to try and help you solve it. :)

Comment: @Ken White. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have DBExpress working fine with MySQL 5.1 in Delphi 2010.
So try putting the libMySQL.DLL in your exe directory may help, as this is first place it will look.
check if you need any other DLL's (I needed dbxmys.dll as well , but working with MySQL)
Set the Params to suit your MySQL server - (Localhost, MyDBName, MyUSerName MyPasswd) then try and connect in the IDE. It works for me!
Chris

Comment: From where did you download the dbExpress and MySQL libs (DLL)?

Comment: They come with Delphi 2010 PRO version